# Mystery Pepper Identification

Tags: identification, peppers

Mystery pepper plant appeared in batch of seeds I germinated. Anyone able to id?[image]

Answer (score 1):

It definitely does not look like pepper.

identify.plantnet.org suggests [Pentas lanceolata (Egyptian star)](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/80589/pentas-lanceolata/details) which has flowers in different shades of pink. I fully agree to that conclusion.

I will call it a nice surprise :D